# Creating New Column In Pandas Dataframe Using Regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a column in a pandas df of type `object` that I want to parse to get the first number in the string, and create a new column containing that number as an `int`.

For example:

Existing df

```
    col
    'foo 12 bar 8'
    'bar 3 foo'
    'bar 32bar 98'
```

Desired df

```
    col               col1
    'foo 12 bar 8'    12
    'bar 3 foo'       3
    'bar 32bar 98'    32
```

I have code that works on any individual cell in the column series

`int(re.search(r'\d+', df.iloc[0]['col']).group())`

The above code works fine and returns 12 as it should. But when I try to create a new column using the whole series:

`df['col1'] = int(re.search(r'\d+', df['col']).group())`

I get the following Error:

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

I tried wrapping a `str()` around `df['col']` which got rid of the error but yielded all 0's in col1

I've also tried converting `col` to a `list` of strings and iterating through the `list`, which only yields the same error. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: check out the `DataFrame.apply()` method. Probably your computation is too complex for a simple assign.

Comment: You might try `df['col'].str.extract(r'(\d+)')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, i'd also add `expand=False`...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That worked perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
new_column = []    
for values in df['col']:
    new_column.append(re.search(r'\d+', values).group())

df['col1'] = new_column
```

the output looks like this:

```
            col    col1
0  foo 12 bar 8      12
1     bar 3 foo       3
2  bar 32bar 98      32
```

Comment: The list has the same name as the regex method (`search`), which I find a bit confusing. `mylist = []`, `mylist.append...` would imho make it a clearer example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58973981/python-create-new-column-with-regex this approach is much better. Using a for loop in a dataframe is an instant red flag