# How to groupby rows into a smaller subset of rows based on similar values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, row

| Company | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Company ABC (Singapore) | 1 |
| Company ABC (Japan) | 3 |
| Company ABC (New York) | 4 |
| Company D | 6 |
| Company D (United Kingdom) | 5 |
| Company D Pte Limited | 3 |

i would like to aggregate the column Company names into the below table, adding a new column ' Aggregated Company' based on the raw datas that i was given in the 1st table. please advise.

| Company | Aggregated Company | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Company ABC (Singapore) | Company ABC | 1 |
| Company ABC (Japan) | Company ABC | 3 |
| Company ABC (New York) | Company ABC | 4 |
| Company D | Company D | 6 |
| Company D (United Kingdom) | Company D | 5 |
| Company D Pte Limited | Company D | 3 |

not sure how to start, tried groupby but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

a simple way is to use pandas' extract method and a regex:

```
import re
re_string = r"(Company \w+) "
df['Aggregated Company'] = df['Company'].str.extract(re_string)
```

use https://regex101.com/ if you would like to test regex strings but I'll explain the regex as written. They are very powerful but it may take some playing around in regex101 to learn.

An explanation of the current string is the word Company, a literal space, then one or more word(\w+) characters, where a word character is [a-zA-z0-9].

The parentheses surrounding the re creates a capturing group which is important for the extract method. It's also the reason I stopped the parentheses before the second space.

an iterative alternate way would be through this answer: [Creating New Column In Pandas Dataframe Using Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46350705/creating-new-column-in-pandas-dataframe-using-regex)